# AJAX CORS webAPI request fails even after the preflight OPTIONS succeeds

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make CORS AJAX "GET" call to an web API service hosted in a test server. webAPI URL = http:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx/api/v1/jobs

I have the following lines of code in WebAPIConfig.cs

```js
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

## AJAX request (from local)

```js
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      datatype: "JSON",
      url: http: xxx: xxx: xxx: xxx / api / v1 / jobs,
      contentType: "application/json";
      charset = utf - 8 ",
            accept: 'application/json',
            beforeSend: BH,            
            success: callback
        }).done(function (data) {
            var str = data.job_id + ': ' + data.job_name;
            $('#responsevalue').text(str);
        }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#responsevalue').text(jqXHR.status + "::" + jqXHR.statusText + "::" + jqXHR.responseText );
        });
```

In Fiddler, I can see the pre-flight request with OPTIONS being sent and the response with 200.

## Fiddler Request Headers:

```html
OPTIONS http:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx/api/v1/jobs HTTP/1.1
Host: 50.17.211.226
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:55346
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: requestdateutc,requestverificationtoken
Connection: keep-alive
```

## Fiddler Response Headers

```html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 20 Nov 2014 14:21:50 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

In Firebug, i can see the following details:

## Firebug Request Headers:

```js
OPTIONS http:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/v1/jobs HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http:localhost:55346
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: requestdateutc,requestverificationtoken
Connection: keep-alive
```

## Firebug Response Headers:

```html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, Content-Type
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 20 Nov 2014 18:08:36 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I read lot of documentation here and in other places. It seems pretty simple and works for everyone (except me).

**Final note: I tested the API with the html page residing in side the test server an it worked fine. Meaning the service and the web page both residing in the same domain.
Additional Info: Browser: Firefox, ASP.NET 4.5, web API 2.2, VS2013 Express**

Thanks in advance and any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your response, it says the allowed headers are `Content-Type, Accept, Content-Type`, but you are asking for `requestdateutc,requestverificationtoken`.  Try explicitly allowing those headers.